# Protobuf gRPC - google protobuf package does not exist

Tags: android, build.gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I am trying to implement gRPC and now I'm having all sorts of issues, but I just don't get what I'm doing wrong. I am following this doc:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/README.md

And now I keep getting such errors when I'm trying to build my project

```
error: package com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 does not exist
com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.Builder<Builder> implements
```

In my Android Studio external libraries I have **protobuf-java-3.12.1 jar**.

In my project gradle file I've added this to dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.14'
```

And in my app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
```

In dependencies I added:

```
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.35.0'
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.35.0'
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.35.0'
compileOnly 'org.apache.tomcat:annotations-api:6.0.53'
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.12.1'
```

And outside of the android tag:

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.12.1"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.35.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, my proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto"; 
option java_package = "com.xxx.xxx.proto.log";
option java_outer_classname = "MyClass";

message MyObject {
    string name = 1;
    string unit = 2;

    oneof value {
         bool bool_value = 3;
         sint32 int32_value = 4;
         uint32 u_int32_value = 5;
         google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp_value = 6;
    }
}
```

When I run:  protoc --version in terminal, this is the output:

```
libprotoc 3.12.1
```

Do I have to add something else or I missed something in my Gradle setup?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are hoping to use protobuf lite (as is normal for Android projects):

```
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.35.0'
...
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.12.1'
```

However, currently you are generating full protobuf code. You need to tell the java and grpc-java code generators to generate for lite via options. As seen in the [grpc-java Android helloworld example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/6db928a791827f7754a9cd24d96eaf7d33975224/examples/android/helloworld/app/build.gradle#L36-L42):

```
protobuf {
    ...
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java { option 'lite' }
            }
            task.plugins {
                grpc { option 'lite' }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Created https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/pull/7865 to fix the documentation.

Comment: Hi Eric, many thanks for your help, but unfortunatelly I'm still getting the same errors...

Comment: Check to make sure you didn't miss any spots that needed the option. Lite generated code extends `GeneratedMessageLite`. So if you see `GeneratedMessageV3`, you are generating full-proto code.

Comment: That's probably because I already had those classes generated and now when I want to use gRPC with lite, it complains?  Should I then use full proto code? Can that work together with gRPC?

Comment: I was finally able to make it working!  I will update the answer..the problem was proto file directory destination and a way of generating proto file. Thank you so much for the assistance!

Comment: @joe can you update your answer to show how you solved the problem